# I need help in implementing a glmm model using Laplace approximation

Tags: r

The model I am trying to implement using laplace approximation i s below:

```
model2<-lmer(ChickWeight$weight~Time + Diet + Time*Diet + (1+Time|Chick), data = ChickWeight)
summary(model2)
```

I was trying to use the code below to do this but i am not sure:

```
#Laplace approximation
 library(glmmsr)
mod_Laplace <- glmm(ChickWeight$weight~Time + Diet + Time*Diet + (1+Time|Chick), data = ChickWeight,
                    family = gaussian, method = "Laplace")
```

I am getting an error as the output

Comment: What is `pseudo` in your `geese`?

Comment: @Quinten the pseudo in my geese will be the conditional mean i think but I do not know how to put that in r